# Set flag only 1 item each group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have source data like this

```
cl1     cl2      cl3     No     
A       A1       AA1     1      
A       A1       AA1     2      
A       A1       AA1     3       
B       B1       BB1     4       
B       B1       BB1     5       
B       B1       BB1     6       
B       B1       BB1     7              
C       C1       CC1     9       
C       C1       CC1     10      
C       C1       CC1     11      
D       D1       DD1     12
```

and the result should be like this

```
cl1     cl2      cl3     No     Flag 
A       A1       AA1     1       1
A       A1       AA1     2       0
A       A1       AA1     3       0   
B       B1       BB1     4       1  
B       B1       BB1     5       0
B       B1       BB1     6       0
B       B1       BB1     7       0       
C       C1       CC1     9       1
C       C1       CC1     10      0
C       C1       CC1     11      0
D       D1       DD1     12      1
```

Each item in group should have an 1 flag with value = 1, other flag items in that group is set to 0.
group by based on cl1, cl2, cl3 but "No" field should include in the result.

I can't figured out how to do this in the SQL.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us. You're probably looking for `row_number` and `lag`.

Comment: @DaleK I'm sorry i can't show you due to complex code, this is just part of code i want to achieve

Comment: thats why you need to create a [MRE] - we certainly don't want to see your entire query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by a, a1, aa1 order by no) = 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from t;
```

If `no` needs to be set, then use a subquery.  Your rows do not have a specified ordering, but you can do:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by a, a1, aa1 order by no) = 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by a, a1, a2) as no
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: i'm really sorry, "No" field is already available in the source. i'll update the question

Comment: @Fadly . . . Then the first query answers your question.